# Validating requests in gateway service and other services

Tags: authentication, security, authorization, microservices, api-gateway

In our implementation, all incoming requests to the API-gateway service are validated using the JWT token and are routed to the corresponding service. But no protection is given for the other service endpoints, ie someone who knows the URL can easily access it directly.

What is the best way to approach this scenario? Do we really need to add request validation at the service level too?

Answer (score 4):

If the "other service endpoints" are exposed through the API gateway to the Internet, then you are right. Anyone can guess the URLs and access them directly. If you're not exposing them to the outside world then you risk that someone who manages to get into your internal network will be able to freely call those services (it can be an attacker, but it can also be a malicious actor from your organisation).

You should always make sure that sensitive endpoints are properly protected, regardless of the fact if they are exposed to the outside world or not.

The services should validate all incoming requests, even the ones that are coming from the API gateway. The API gateway should make a coarse-grained validation of credentials, e.g., check whether the token exists, has a valid signature, and isn't expired. The service should then validate again the signature and expiration, and make fine-grained validation. E.g., check whether the subject of the token has permission to access the given data.

The service should not blindly trust incoming requests only because those endpoints sit behind an API gateway. Someone might find a loophole in your API gateway and the validation made at the service level will give you another level of protection.

Comment: Thank you @Michal Trojanowski for the reply